# Call to clojure.core/defn did not conform to spec

Tags: clojure

I have a small game that I'm writing in Clojure. I am very new to the language and one of the first errors I've stumbled upon is

**Call to clojure.core/defn did not conform to spec.**

I have no idea what causes the error, but an exception is thrown with this:

```
  (ns survival-text.core
  (:gen-class))

(def health 10)
(def hunger 10)
(def locations ["plains" "ocean" "mountains" "forest"])
(def currentLocation (atom 0))

(defn walk
  (def random rand-int (count locations))
  (reset! currentLocation (atom random)))

(defn choices
  [input]
  (case (input)
    "walk" (walk)
    "exit" (System/exit 0)
    ""))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (while true
    (def input read-line)
    (choices input)))
```

But not this:

```
  (ns survival-text.core
  (:gen-class))

(def health 10)
(def hunger 10)
(def locations ["plains" "ocean" "mountains" "forest"])
(def currentLocation (atom 0))

(defn choices
  [input]
  (case (input)
    "walk" (reset! currentLocation (atom (rand-nth locations)))
    "exit" (System/exit 0)
    ""))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (while true
    (def input read-line)
    (choices input)))
```

This is what is being thrown at me

```
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/defn at (survival_text/core.clj:9:1).
Call to clojure.core/defn did not conform to spec.
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.checkSpecs(Compiler.java:6971)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1(Compiler.java:6987)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand(Compiler.java:7074)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7160)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:463)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:428)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__6824.invoke(core.clj:6126)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6125)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6109)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5908)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5903)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6765.invoke(core.clj:5948)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5928)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5985)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5969)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6007)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6007)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at user$eval140$fn__144.invoke(form-init1707647033589713549.clj:1)
        at user$eval140.invokeStatic(form-init1707647033589713549.clj:1)
        at user$eval140.invoke(form-init1707647033589713549.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7166)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:454)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:454)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:485)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:519)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:516)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to clojure.core/defn did not conform to spec. {:clojure.spec.alpha/problems ({:path [:fn-tail :arity-1 :params], :pred clojure.core/vector?, :val (def random rand-int (count locations)), :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/defn-args :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list], :in [1]} {:path [:fn-tail :arity-n :bodies :params], :pred clojure.core/vector?, :val def, :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/defn-args :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list], :in [1 0]}), :clojure.spec.alpha/spec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2509 0x41e68d87 "clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2509@41e68d87"], :clojure.spec.alpha/value (walk (def random rand-int (count locations)) (reset! currentLocation (atom random))), :clojure.spec.alpha/args (walk (def random rand-int (count locations)) (reset! currentLocation (atom random)))}
        at clojure.spec.alpha$macroexpand_check.invokeStatic(alpha.clj:705)
        at clojure.spec.alpha$macroexpand_check.invoke(alpha.clj:697)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.checkSpecs(Compiler.java:6969)
        ... 44 more
```

I am using leiningen and I haven't changed anything an all apart from the src/survival-text/core.clj

What causes the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Seems like the `walk` function is missing its arguments?

Comment: Note for the future that our rules requires code given in a question to be a [mre] -- the *shortest possible code* that produces a specific problem. Taking things out until you observe that `walk` causes the problem, and thus posting *only* `walk` and no other part of your code, is part of what you're expected to do when getting ready to ask the question. In addition to the above link to our Help Center, see http://sscce.org/, including in particular the "Tricks for Trimming" section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the args list.  It should look like:

```
(defn walk
  []  ; no args to this function
  (let [random (rand-int (count locations))]
    (reset! currentLocation random)))
```

You may also want to review Clojure intro material like [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/) or [Getting Clojure](https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure) for an introduction.  In particular, it is generally not a good idea to use `(def ...)` inside of a function.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the additional material, I will look into it
Also, forgot the brackets around rand-int

Comment: @AlanThompson, ...would you contradict the assertion that this resolution puts the question into the "simple typographical error" category / close reason?

Comment: It is a simple error of not understanding the args vector in a `defn` expression. However the error msg `Call to clojure.core/defn did not conform to spec.` doesn't do much to help a new user figure out what corrective action is needed.